# Is there a way to confirm data in Firebase RealTime Database?

Tags: firebase, android-studio, firebase-realtime-database

I'm registering users and as we all do by using getUid() as a key, it registers more than one people against same email or same phone number, I implemented the method to stop that but when there is no user it get's stuck in the loop for checking if the user with given number or mail exists or not.
I mean we cann loop through the data when it's there but when it isn't how could we conclude that no user has been registered yet or there is no data yet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got something to work, here is the sample

```
            table_user.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                // Check user exist in database  or not
                if (dataSnapshot.child(userPhone).exists()) {

                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "User is Exist with this phone number!!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    et_phoneNo.setError("No is already registered");
                    et_phoneNo.requestFocus();
                    et_phoneNo.setText("");
                    return;
                }
                if (userPhone.length() < 11) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please Enter Correct Phone No", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    return;
                }
                if (TextUtils.isEmpty(userName) || TextUtils.isEmpty(userPassword) || TextUtils.isEmpty(userPhone)) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please Fill all required Field", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                } else {

                    PhoneAuthProvider.getInstance().verifyPhoneNumber(
                            userPhone,        // Phone number to verify
                            60,                 // Timeout duration
                            TimeUnit.SECONDS,   // Unit of timeout
                            orederondoor.com.projectorder.Shopkeeper.Shopkeeper_Pages.Sign_Up.this,               // Activity (for callback binding)
                            mCallbacks);        // OnVerificationStateChangedCallbacks
                }
            }
            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
            }
        });
```

Comment: I can't. Have to wait for two days